# Heat maps with bar plots or mosaic plots in r

Tags: image, r, matrix, histogram

I have a matrix showing the trait similarity between species at 2 different sites i.e.

```
relationship<-matrix(1:6,ncol=2)
colnames(relationship)<-c("Sp1","Sp2")
rownames(relationship)<-c("Sp3","Sp4","Sp5")

     Sp1 Sp2
Sp3   1   4
Sp4   2   5
Sp5   3   6
```

I  also have a matrix showing their abundance at each site

```
abundance<-matrix(1:5,ncol=1)
rownames(abundance)<-c("Sp1","Sp2","Sp3","Sp4","Sp5")
colnames(abundance)<-"abundance"

       abundance
 Sp1         1
 Sp2         2
 Sp3         3
 Sp4         4
 Sp5         5
```

I would like to create either a heat map with a bar plots along the axes like this:

[image]

UPDATE TO ORIGINAL QUESTION

Alternatively (as suggested by BenBarnes ) I would like to create a mosaic plot using the abundances to control the size of the tiles and the matrix to indicate the 'intensity' of the colour. So very crudely for the example above the mosaic plot would look like this:

[image]

Also I would like to know your opinion on which method most clearly displays the relationship between the species as well as the relationship between their abundances?

Comment: Would you consider using a mosaic plot? Either from the [`graphics`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/mosaicplot.html) or [`vcd`](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/vcd/html/mosaic.html) package?

Comment: Sure! As long as the final goal is achieved I am very flexible to how it is done. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: So would this involve creating 2 contingency tables for abundance and then using the relationship matrix to specify 'tile' colour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `graphics`  package functions (barplot, image, etc.) you can do something like this.

```
bp1 <- barplot(t(abundance[3:5, ]), width = 0.2, space = 0.7, plot = FALSE)
bp2 <- barplot(t(abundance[1:2, ]), horiz = TRUE, width = 0.05, space = 1, plot = FALSE)


par(fig = c(0, 0.8, 0, 0.8), new = TRUE)
par(xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")
image(relationship)
par(fig = c(0, 0.8, 0.55, 1), new = TRUE)
barplot(t(abundance[3:5, ]), width = 0.2, space = 0.7)
text(bp1, abundance[3:5,] - 0.5, c("Sp3", "Sp4", "Sp5"))
par(fig = c(0.65, 1, 0, 0.8), new = TRUE)   
barplot(t(abundance[1:2, ]), horiz = TRUE, width = 0.05, space = 1)
text(abundance[1:2,] - 0.5, bp2, c("Sp1", "Sp2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was very useful. Could you please explain what is happening in the different steps of your code.